# Make sidebar (in React) take up 100% of the height of the page even when there's scrolling

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

Most of the pages in my application fit within the viewport, so up until now I've been using `height: 100vh` for my `<SideNav />` component. But now a couple of my pages scroll and this breaks the functionality of the sidebar, since it abruptly ends when you start scrolling.

However `height: 100%` also does not work, and in fact the sidebar ends up being even shorter. How do I make the sidebar always stretch the entire length of the page? I'd like to avoid using `position: absolute` since this will require setting a bunch of fixed left margins on the rest of my content.

Note that I am using React with styled-components.

Comment: This isn't really a React question. You should probably post your rendered HTML and any relevant CSS.

Comment: Have you tried thinking about making your sidebar sticky while the main content scrolls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a sticky sidebar to keep your sidebar static while the page scrolls. This can be done using CSS or by implementing a react component.

It can be implemented using css like this:

```
position: -webkit-sticky;
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

This is applied to a top bar navigation but you can determine which elements are sticky in your component. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sticky

Comment: The one remaining issue with this is that if I open the Devtools (docked to the bottom), then reload the page, then close the Devtools, the sidebar doesn't go all the way to the bottom. I think this is an inherent issue with 100vh, but I'm not sure if there's a way around this.

Comment: Are your users going to be opening the dev tools and closing them while using your site/app? Seems pretty specific. I rarely resize my browser when surfing the web. I only resize during development. Does it look fine when opened on different dimensions?

Comment: Even if they don't, I just found another issue with 100vh. Any content on the page that is outside of the viewport doesn't calculate its margin/padding against the sidebar, but rather against the left side of the page (since the sidebar technically doesn't exist outside of the viewport on load). Is there no CSS property or function I can use to ensure the sidebar actually takes up the full height of the page content?